# Separability measures

Tags: machine-learning, references, pattern-recognition

I am just studying pattern recognition. In that regard, my question is 
Why we need separability measures? 
Would you please give me detail explanation and suggest some books to read?

Answer (score 2):

I think the main use of separability measures is to asses the quality of your chosen features under a given classification problem without relying in accuracy estimates for particular classifiers.

And, sometimes you may have a pretty bad performance under a given classifier, so, it might be because your classifier is not appropriate to deal with your data (i.e. you are using a classifier giving linear decision boundaries, when class separation in your data is non linear), or because your data cannot be separable under any kind of decision function (distribution of target classes for your data points approaches randomness)

I found cut edge weight statistic (Zighed, Djamel A., et al., 2002. "Separability Index in Supervised Learning. Principles of Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery".) useful for this purpose.